# D365 CRM->Activity(Activity Pointer) hide "Button 1" for all the activities like Task, Phonecall, Appointment except for Email records on the HomeGrid

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm-ribbon-workbench

Microsoft Dynamics CRM(365) CE(Csutomer Engagement)

I have a custom "Button 1" on the Email entity Home Grid, all the activity record (Appointments, Email, Phonecall, Task etc) are displayed in "Activities" section.

I would like to hide the custom "Button 1" on the Home Grid of Activity(Activity Pointer) for all the Activity(Activity Pointer) like Task, Phonecall, Appointment except for "Email" records.

there are multiple views listed under "Activities" like (Appointments, Email, Phonecall, Task etc)

The custom "Button 1" is required to display on Email views listed under Activities->Email->Home Grid

I have working code using scripting, is it possible without scripting and using RibbonWorkbench or update the Application ribbon XML

I tried using scripting and have working solutions, but I have to hard code the Email view name to show custom "Button 1" only for Email views within Activity(Activity Pointer) Home Grid